# I have an array and I want to get new array which value is greaterthan 60

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6

I have an array and I want to get new array of the elements whose valus are greater than 60

This is an array.

```
const ages = [23,62,45,234,2,62,234,62,34];
```

I want to get new array from this array which value has greate than 60.

Expected Result: `[ 62, 234, 62, 234, 62 ]`

Comment: And what have you tried, what where the result of your research?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code will help. Use a simple filter array and store results in a new constant.

```
const old = ages.filter(age => age >= 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an another solution. Just check the values that are greater than 60 and push them into the new array.

```
var greaterages = [];
const ages = [23,62,45,234,2,62,234,62,34];
for (var i = ages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(ages[i] > 60) {
        greaterages.push(ages[i]);
    }
}
console.log(greaterages);
```

Comment: Using the Array filter method as in @Ankit's answer is cleaner: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter